# How to convert multiple CSV files in directory to pipe-delimited text files using Python3

Tags: python-3.x, loops, csv

So I'm new to Python(3) and need to create a loop that will go through almost 200 CSV files and convert them each into a pipe-delimited .txt file (with the same name).

I have code that does this for 1 file and works perfectly:

```
import csv

with open('C:/Path/InputFile.csv', 'r') as fin, \
open('C:/Path/OutputFile.txt', 'w') as fout:
reader = csv.DictReader(fin)
writer = csv.DictWriter(fout, reader.fieldnames, delimiter='|')
writer.writeheader()
writer.writerows(reader)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would modify your code to:

```
 for in_name, out_name in zip(list_of_in_names, list_of_out_names):
     with open(in_name, 'r') as fin, open(out_name, 'w') as fout:
         ...
```

Where `list_of_in_names` and `list_of_out_names` names of files you want to read from and write to respectively.

Edit: To address the issue from the comments you can use the `pathlib` library:

```
from pathlib import Path

for in_path in Path('C:/Path').glob('*.csv'):
     out_path = in_path.with_suffix('.txt')
     with in_path.open('r') as fin, out_path.open('w') as fout:
         ...
```

Comment: Thanks Davis, but I was looking for a loop that would just go through the files in the directory on its own, instead of me having to create a list.